# Add an extra parameter to a delegate / function as a parameter

Tags: c#, delegates

**Context:**
I am getting data from a legacy backend system which I dynamically deserialize with:

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
```

I am dynamically processing this result with:

```
public static Result<IEnumerable<T>>? GetResultList<T>(ResponseResult<IEnumerable<T>> response,
    Func<IEnumerable<T>, Result<IEnumerable<T>>>? processSuccessResponse = null)
{
    if (response == null)
        return null;

    var errorMessage = response.Header?.ErrorMessage;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errorMessage))
        return Result<IEnumerable<T>>.Failure(ErrorPrefix + errorMessage);

    if (response.Value == null || !response.Value.Any())
        return null;

    return processSuccessResponse == null
        ? Result<IEnumerable<T>>.Success(response.Value)
        : processSuccessResponse(response.Value);
}
```

With the processSuccessResponse param I can dynamically invoke another simple function, for example sorting the Value.

**Question:**
For one specific type I would like to **add an extra parameter** to a delegate/fuction as parameter so I can enrich the result afterwards:

```
foreach (var res in result!.Value!)
{
    res.OrderId = request.OrderId;
}
```

Otherwise, I need to check for null values again in the calling method, which I would like to avoid, eg:

```
var result = ResultHandler.GetResultList(response!);
if (result == null || result.Value == null || !result.Value.Any())
{
    return result;
}

foreach (var res in result!.Value!)
{
    res.OrderId = request.OrderId;
}
```

I've read various questions here on SO concerning delegates and/or currying, however I just do not get it exactly for my situation. I've tried for example:

```
public static Func<string, Result<IEnumerable<OrderStatus>>> EnrichWithOrderId(IEnumerable<OrderStatus> list)
{
    return (string orderId) =>
    {
        foreach (var status in list)
        {
            status.OrderId = orderId;
        }

        return Result<IEnumerable<OrderStatus>>.Success(list);
    };
}
```

This seems to work, but I do not get how to call it:

```
return ResultHandler.GetResultList<OrderStatus>((response) => EnrichWithOrderId(request.OrderId, response.Value));
```

or:

```
return ResultHandler.GetResultList<OrderStatus>((response, EnrichWithOrderId(request.OrderId)(response.Value));
```

Because the types are not matching now and / or because:
"Cannot convert lambda expression to type .. because it is not a delegate type"

So, I am wondering if I could add an extra parameter to a function (which is also a parameter) or maybe a nice alternative to avoid some code duplication in my situation.

Comment: C# is a language of types. What number and type of parameters does `EnrichWithOrderId` take? Where are you passing that in to it?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the function as follows (switch the before mentioned string and IEnumerable) and then it works:

```
public static Func<IEnumerable<OrderStatus>, Result<IEnumerable<OrderStatus>>> EnrichWithOrderId(string orderId)
{
    return (IEnumerable<OrderStatus> list) =>
    {
        foreach (var status in list)
        {
            status.OrderId = orderId;
        }

        return Result<IEnumerable<OrderStatus>>.Success(list);
    };
}
```

And call it like:

```
return ResultHandler.GetResultList(response!, EnrichWithOrderId(request.OrderId));
```

Only slight issue here is that the function is called first as well, when calling the main method